# how to create clean urls using htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have a property website where alot of properties have been uploaded, presently the url of a property looks like this

```
http://propertyonline.com.ng/property.php?product_id=255
```

But for the sake of google optimization i know it should not remain like this so i am try to rewrite my url to something clean like the title of the property.

so instead of e.g

```
http://propertyonline.com.ng/property.php?product_id=255
```

we will have

```
http://propertyonline.com.ng/3 Bedroom Flat Large Compound On Banana Island Ikoyi
```

i have a variable that presently echos the title of the property when on this page dynamically based on the id of the property as above

```
<?php  echo $row_prop['title']; ?>
```

Please how can i rewrite the url dynamically using htaccess

thanks

Comment: read about .htaccess tutorials. there plenty on the internet. try what you learned and then post here the issue if you faced something

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can format the URL as:

```
http://propertyonline.com.ng/{product_id}-{product_slug}
```

`{product_id}` is numeric value, and `{product_slug}` can be any string followed by the product id. Then you can use this `RewriteRule`. `$1` is back-reference to the grouped part `([0-9]+)`, represented to `{product_id}`. `[^/]*` matches any string except the forward slash character, represented to `{product_slug}`.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-[^/]* /property.php?product_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want clean url use product slug 
For slug use below code which will remove spaces and unwanted chars from string

```
function to_prety_url($str)
{
    if($str !== mb_convert_encoding( mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-32') )
        $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($str));
    $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $str = preg_replace('`&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|uml|circ|grave|ring|cedil|slash|tilde|caron|lig);`i', '\1', $str);
    $str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $str = preg_replace(array('`[^a-z0-9]`i','`[-]+`'), '-', $str);
    $str = strtolower( trim($str, '-') );
    return $str;
}
```

change your .htaccess code (or add)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/$    index.php    [L]

#this is for product section
RewriteRule ^property/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    property.php?slug=$1  [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.akshadainfosystem.com/

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```